# Ubuntu 9.10 Dowload Speed Very Slow

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, slow-connection

I'm running Ubuntu 9.10 desktop and I'm new to the Linux world, so bear with me.

I'm on a corporate network of 3 T1s shared across 50-60 users. I typically get about 300 KB/sec for downloads, but for whatever reason, the Linux box will start out in that range, then drop to less than 1KB/Sec sometimes. Doesn't seen to matter where I'm downloading from. Right now I'm trying to get Eclipse for PHP and it's running at 3-6KB/sec. Getting the updates for the system will also drop to very slow rates.

Our IT person has set up the machine to get the same 10.0.0.x address when it starts, and moved this IP to bypass our Proxy/Firewall going out, so that shouldn't be the issue.

Can anyone recommend something I can try to better diagnose the problem. Again, I'm new to the Linux world and the hardware/OS setup side in general (coming form more of a coding background).

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

Check the output of ifconfig.  The following counts should be 0 or nearly 0:  errors, frame, collision, overruns, and carrier.  If not you likely have a duplex mismatch on the line.  If the line is configured to fixed speed and duplex, Linux will be unable to negotiate correctly.  Speed can be determined by other mechanisms, but duplex is only available in the negotiation info.